# `any()` vs multiple use of `or` in `if` statement: difference in behavior

Tags: python-3.x

When I have to write if statements that should evaluate to `True` if any of the specified conditions evaluate to `True`, I was accustomed to use many `or` infix between my conditions.

example:

`if customer.value > 5000 or \
    customer.orders > 50 or \
    customer.join_at < datetime(2010,10,12) or \
    customer.name == 'Hal':`

Recently, I realized I could do this instead.

`if any((customer.value > 5000, 
         customer.orders > 50, 
         customer.join_at < datetime(2010,10,12), 
         customer.name == 'Hal')):`

which, IMO, is easier on the eyes.

Before I go back through my code and make changes, I wanted to ask the knowledgeable StackOverflow community if there were any performance difference or other caveats between the two methods. *likewise for multiple uses of `and` vs `all`*

What happens if I use a generator instead of a tuple. Will it cycle through until a StopIteration is raised?

example:

```
def g():
    yield isinstance('0', str)
    yield isinstance(0, str)
    yield isinstance('abc', str)

mygen = g()

any(boolean for boolean in mygen)
# returns True, but does it go through the whole generator.
```

Comment: Don't jump straight in to performance considerations. Check if both of them are working fine and pick the one which suits your usecase the most. If you get performance hit, profile the application and if the profiling boils your problem down to this part, then you can worry about picking the fastest of these two.

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye, I didn't mean to jump straight to performance issues, more interested in other caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any()` and `all()` do not short-circuit in the same manner if a sequence such as the tuple in your question is used; all elements will be evaluated.

Also, `any()` and `all()` only ever return boolean values, and do not coalesce as `or` and `and` do.

Comment: Thanks, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, what happens if I use a generator instead of a tuple. Will it cycle through until a StopIteration is raised? -- updating my question with this follow up.

Comment: It will stop and return `False` when the first negative condition is found, otherwise it will return `True`.